# Free chart library for creating lines, bar (stacked & grouped) and combined in Android

Tags: android, charts

I have an application in which I need to create below types of charts:

- Lines
- Bar/Column (grouped and stacked)
- Combined (lines and bar)

In addition, it will be good to have below features if possible:

- Support
- Package constantly updated (not out-dated)
- Well documented
- Easy to integrate

I have seen a lot of them:

- [Grap View](http://www.android-graphview.org/)
- [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/)
- [Charts4j](https://code.google.com/p/charts4j/)
- [afreechart](https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/)
- [HelloCharts for android](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android)

**Grap View**
Looks like it is well-documented, it has support and it is updated constantly. Also easy to integrate but I do not see it supports creation of stacked and grouped bar charts... so it is not good for me. Could anyone confirm me if it is possible to create grouped and stacked bar charts with it?

**AChartEngine**
It seems like it has not support for grouped bar charts. It is out-dated (last version May 2013), and it does not explain how to integrate it. It seems well-documented and with support as it has a discussion group.

Could anyone confirm me if it supports grouped charts?

**Charts4j**
Well-documented, supports grouped and stacked bar charts. Also line charts but I am not sure if it supported combined graphs (bar with lines) so anyone can confirm me?

It is out-dated... last version comes from January 2011.

**afreechart**
A lot of chart types, including lines, grouped bar charts but.... it seems it has no support for stacked bar charts..... someone can confirm this? Out-dated as last version is April 2012. I cannot see an explanation on how to integrate it.

**HelloCharts**
It supports all the chart types I am searching for: lines, column/bar (grouped and stacked supported). Also it is possible to combine line with bar charts.

It explains briefly how to integrate it with different options and a quick guide on how to start using it. It seems easy to integrate.

From git it seems very updated. It has examples but I cannot see any API documentation or documentation of any other type or even a wiki page. Creating issues or make questions it is possible by creating in issue from its page.

**Conclusion**
Regarding to my needs, I think I am going to use HelloCharts but before doing this I would like to someone confirm me my doubts about the other packages and share opinions on what package is best for me to use according to my needs.

Comment: could you please assist me with implementing stacked bar and line chart in same graph using Hellochart?

Comment: Hey I used MPAndroid charts by phil joda and it works fairly well but the pie chart does not have a call out feature. Does anyone a lib that allows for call out labels to be drawn around the pie chart ? thanks

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked into charting libraries for the web?  You can add charts inside your android app by using a WebView and enabling javascript

```
setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
```

Theres quite a selection of charts in javascript:

[d3js](http://d3js.org/)

[ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com/features/responsive-charts/)

[chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)

I personally use ZingChart; it has svg support for high pixel density devices and recognizes touch input. It's free with a watermark.

Comment: Good to know, thanks very much! I will have a look although I have not so much experience using javascript...Finally, I discovered MPAndroidChart, it is very similar to HelloCharts, but it seems more powerful.

Comment: Wowww! Using WebView does not seem to be a good idea as recently was discovered a vulnerability on it. See below:: http://www.360safe.com/news/2015/01/19/ways-to-secure-android-from-google-webview-vulnerability/

Comment: MoAndroidChart is great and well documented... only issue is it do not support compound graphs(i.e graph with multiple types of plot...like stacked bar and line chart in same graph)... only reason i moved to HelloChart library

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked MPAndroidChart by Mr. Jahoda? I have only checked it out briefly though. I've seen that it has quite a good wiki and very nice customizable features for design. Everything you mentioned that you needed are provided by it. (I'm quite doubtful about the stacked bar though. I haven't seen it in the examples)